# iOS UITableView prevent from scrolling

Tags: ios, uitableview

I want to get information about how UITableView would be scrolled without actually schange `scrollView.contentOffset`. I cant use `scrollEnabled` property becouse its stop fireing `scrollViewDidScroll` event on table and I need it. Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is a little bit hard to understand but in any case scrolling on a `UITableView` **will** modify `contentOffset`. That's how the superclass, `UIScrollView`, works.

As for `scrollViewDidScroll`, it is only called automatically when the user scrolls the view, but you can override `setContentOffset` to trigger it manually when needed. Just to avoid a loop set a `BOOL dragging = YES` flag on `scrollViewWillBeginDragging:` and clear it on `scrollViewDidEndDragging:willDecelerate:`.